# Https access through WildFly module

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-10

I have custom logging-handler defined for WildFly (defined with `module.xml`) that needs to send logging events through https.

I tried to simply use `HttpURLConnection` but the sending just does not proceed (it seems that no exception is thrown).
The code works in non-JBoss environment.

Should I declare somehow that the module uses http module?

Answer (score 0):

No need for anything. The problem was elsewhere. (The request failed but it didn't invoke exception)